# Authentication Issue in Python/Rest

Tags: python, rest, api, jira

My issue is that I keep getting a "Response [401]" which I from what I have seen online means there is an authentication error. I am trying to create a new user via Rest calls in python. I am quite new to Python/Rest so I am sure there is something I am missing.

Below is my code:

```
import requests
import json
import base64

print("Script Running")
username = ‘UN’
password = ‘PW’
tempString = username + ':' + password
encodedString = base64.b64encode(tempString.encode())
data = {"name": "changeUser", "password": "12345","emailAddress": "emailaddress@some.com","displayName": "changeUser","notification" : "false"}
url = "http://myserver.atlassian.net/rest/api/2/user/"
headers = {'Authentication': 'Basic ' + tempString, 'Content-type': 'application/json', 'Accept': 'application/json', 'X-Atlassian-Token': 'no-check' }

print(encodedString)
r = requests.post(url, json.dumps(data), headers)
print(r)
print("Script Ending")
```

encodedString returns b'stringofstuff='
print(r) returns Response[401]

Comment: Have you verified that the authentication information are valid against the actual service?

Comment: Yes. I am able to use the authentication credentials against the instance. I have double checked the all the spelling to make sure it was not a spelling error

Comment: You can use curl to mess around with your query and see the responses.
curl -D- -u UN:PW -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" https://myserver.atlassian.net/rest/api/2/user -d '{"name": "changeUser", "password": "12345","emailAddress": "emailaddress@some.com","displayName": "changeUser","notification" : "false"}'

Answer (score 0):

requests has options for all of this. I'd just use

```
r = requests.post(url, json=data, auth=(username, password))
```

Comment: when I used this method I ended up getting a response[404] instead of 401. Doesnt this mean the site is unavailable/not responding

Comment: Jira sometimes returns 404 when the problem is totally unrelated to page not found. Is there an errorMessages field in the response?

Answer (score 0):

Have you used a separate HTTP client to make this call? Try using Postman to make the call using the same data so you can determine where to start looking first.

Also - What exactly are you supposed to be doing with encodedString? The only time you use it is in the print call.

Comment: I have used PostMan but have not had any luck with it either. Right now encodedString is just tempString being changed to base64. When I change out tempString for encodedString in the call, it throws an error

Comment: If you can't make a call to the server via Postman, you should start trouble shooting your authentication methods before worrying about your code.

Comment: I have used Postman to make GET calls before but never POST. The credentials I used in Postman ad the same I used in my code, so there shouldnt be an issue with the credentials